# UserId in formula field

Tags: formula, formula-field, fields, account-teams

I want to insert UserId of the SObject AccountTeamMember  in a formula field, but I'm not able to put this field...
How can I do it?

We can see in the pic that I don't have the option to put UserId in the formula.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put in the formula `User.Id` and it's working

Answer (score 0):

Formula fields do not support your business need. Instead, make use of a Flow configured through the [Flow Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.flow_builder.htm&type=5). Here are some high level steps you can follow:

1. Create record-triggered flow to run when your Account is create and/or update.
2. Your Flow should run after-save.
3. You should create a Get Records block to query the Account Team Member object with a filter on `AccountId`.
4. Create an Assignment block to set the Account field with the single result from the Get Records block i.e your Account Team Member ID.
5. You need to finish with an Update Records block with no conditions configured.

Something like this:

[image]